# Routing causing 'w is not afunction'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get: `Error: w is not a function`

**scripts/app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'homepageControllers',
    'ngRoute'
]);


app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home-page.html',
            controller: 'homePageCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/homepage'
        });
  }]);
```

**scripts/controllers/homepageController.js**

```
var homepageControllers = angular.module('homepageControllers', []);
homepageControllers.controller('homePageCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller loaded");
});
```

**views/home-page.html**

```
<div>
    Work ffs!
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I'm new to angular and followed [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) tutorial step-by-step. Google doesn't have the answer, ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you included the ngRoute js file?

Comment: Also `w` seems to be a minified name; could you run your app with the unminified version of the libraries? It may provide more information on what `w` is.

Comment: Please see  my comments to @Cétia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a [minifying issue](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05). You should force dependency injections mapping :

Transform this :

**scripts/controllers/homepageController.js**

```
var homepageControllers = angular.module('homepageControllers', []);
homepageControllers.controller('homePageCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller loaded");
});
```

to this :

**scripts/controllers/homepageController.js**

```
var homepageControllers = angular.module('homepageControllers', []);
homepageControllers.controller('homePageCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller loaded");
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, i've used unminified library of angular as @Nikos Paraskevopoulos suggested and the error is gone. But if i keep the minified version your solution does not work for me. So minified shows unclear error, while the unminified does not produce it at all.

Comment: Yeah you totally have a minifying issue which is a really common problem in angular . .. I suggest you to re-read my answer and the link I posted about minifying issue.